# Equation of the line perpendicular to a line and passing through the point of intersection of another two lines.

Tags: linear-algebra

Write the equation of the line perpendicular to:
4x + 2y + 2= 0 and passing through the point of intersection of the lines:
2x - 7 = 0 and 4y + 28 = 0.

So, if the line we are trying to find the equation of is perpendicular to 4x + 2y + 2= 0, then it's slope must be -1/2. So the equation will go like: y=-1/2 + ...

In the question, it says that it passes through the point of intersection of the lines 2x - 7 = 0 and 4y + 28 = 0. Normally, I would equalize the "y"s in the equations. However, the first equation's y value is 0 (I guess). So this is where I got stuck.

Comment: If $2x-7=0$ then what's $x$? If $4y+28=0$ then what's $y$? Point of intersection can be interpreted as "makes both statements true at the same time."

Answer (score 1):

Firs you find the slope of the given line, $$ 4x+2y +2=0$$ which is the same as $$ y=-2x-1$$, and the slope is $-2$

The slope if the perpendicular line is opposite reciprocal of $-2$ which is $ 1/2$

The point of intersection of the two given lines  is $(7/2, -7)$, therefore the desired line is $$ y+7 = 1/2 (x- 7/2) $$

or  $$ y = 1/2 (x- 7/2)-7 $$

Answer (score 0):

The point of intersection is
$$M\left(\frac 72,-7\right)$$

the equation we look for is

$$y=\frac 12 x+C$$

it contains $M$ if

$$-7=\frac 74+C$$

which gives
$$C=\frac{-35}{4}$$